# Magento admin menu item

Tags: magento, menu, module, menuitem

I looked through many sites and articles about adding items to admin menu in magento, some examples I copied one to one and I haven't gotten any result. Please tell me what I did wrong?

I have the module SmartLetter, it's showing in the module list.

Magento ver. 1.9.2.2

The path to the module folder is - `app ▸ code ▸ local ▸ Chu ▸ SmartLetter`

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Chu_SmartLetter>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Chu_SmartLetter>
    </modules>
    <global>

    </global>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <smartletter translate="title" module="smartletter">
            <title>Smart Letter</title>
            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
        </smartletter>
    </menu>
        <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <smartletter translate="title" module="smartletter">
                                        <title>SmartLetter Section</title>
                                    </smartletter>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a helper for your module, does useful stuff like translations which the menu required.

Create a helper under `app/code/local/Chu/SmartLetter/Helper/Data.php`:

```
<?php

class Chu_SmartLetter_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

Add it to your global config.xml definition:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <chu_smartletter>
            <class>Chu_SmartLetter_Helper</class>
        </chu_smartletter>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Update your adminhtml.xml to use the `module="chu_smartletter"`

On a side note I would recommend not to clutter the top level menu, is your module *that* important? I would nest it under one of the existing menu items.

Comment: Thanx it works, but when I copy this module to magento (1.7.0.2) the menu didn't show. And why can I use <smartletter> tag if the module name chu_smartletter, I saw modules where the name of module and the tags in config absolutly different but working.

Comment: You can use the `smartlatter` module name or whatever you want for that matter as long as it is defined in the global helper xml, but it is best practise to include the module namespace `chu` so it is easier to find in the future.